# The <email address> doesn't appear on profile when using Markdown obfuscation?

Tags: discussion, markdown

If I enter the text `<me@example.com>` on my profile page, it does not appear. Is this part of Markdown supported by SE?

I saw this on [Markdown's page](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#autolink):

> Automatic links for email addresses work similarly, except that Markdown will also perform a bit of randomized decimal and hex entity-encoding to help obscure your address from address-harvesting spambots. For example, Markdown will turn this:
>
> `<address@example.com>`
>
> into something like this:
>
> `<a href="&#x6D;&#x61;i&#x6C; ... &#109;">&#x61;&#x64; ... &#109;</a>`
>
> which will render in a browser as a clickable link to “address@example.com”.

Comment: (As an aside: [Does email address obfuscation actually work?](http://superuser.com/questions/235937/does-email-address-obfuscation-actually-work) on Super User, and [Does e-mail obfuscation really make automatic harvesting harder?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1259363/does-e-mail-obfuscation-really-make-automatic-harvesting-harder) on Stack Overflow.)

Comment: Do you indeed use backticks to get `code` for that? If not, then it's just a disallowed HTML element for the sanitizer? And either case: how is using `<...>` a Markdown obfuscation? The only Markdown usage I can find is for URLs. Like `<http://example.com>` can *enforce* clickable links for difficult URLs that are hard to recognize automatically.

Comment: @arjan I updated the question.

Comment: Okay, confirmed that neither `<me@example.com>` nor `<mailto:me@example.com>` gets one a clickable link (despite the mentioning in the Markdown help). This also applies to questions and answers. Even `<a href="mailto:me@example.com">me@example.com</a>` is not clickable.

Comment: Anyway: so it's not for [obfuscation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obfuscation), but you want a clickable link, right?

Comment: @arjan it's for both obfuscation and clickability

Comment: ...how does that obfuscate anything? What do you expect the result to be then?

Comment: @arjan that link says that the address will turned into <a href="&#x6D;&#x61;i&#x6C;&#x74;&#x6F;:&#x61;&#x64;&#x64;&#x72;&#x65;
&#115;&#115;&#64;&#101;&#120;&#x61;&#109;&#x70;&#x6C;e&#x2E;&#99;&#111;
&#109;">&#x61;&#x64;&#x64;&#x72;&#x65;&#115;&#115;&#64;&#101;&#120;&#x61;
&#109;&#x70;&#x6C;e&#x2E;&#99;&#111;&#109;</a>

Answer (score 1):

We do not support email addresses in Markdown; this is by design.

Comment: Oh, I see. Any reason why?